# Subtracting values from a given cell, if those values are on a row with another cell with matching criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have what I imagine to be a simple enough formula, but drawing a mental blank on how to do this one.

```
A  |  B   |  C  |  D   |  E
Row|Line 1|Line2|Line3|| Value
1  |0     |  1  |  0   |  200
2  |0     |  0  |  1   |  100
3  |1     |  0  |  1   |  500
```

So I have capacity value for each line, and what I want to do is the following.

For any given Line, if a 1 appears, subtract the value in the last column from the capacity.

For example, if I say that each line capacity is 1000:
Line 1 = 1000, subtract 500 from row 3.
Line 2 = 1000, subtract 200 from row 1.
Line 3 = 1000, subtract 100 from row 2 and 500 from row 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume source table occupies A1:D3, capacity occupies E1.
Put the next formula to A4 cell:

```
=$E$1-SUMPRODUCT(A1:A3,$D1:$D3)
```

Drag it till C4.

The result is:

```
      A     B     C     D     E
    -----------------------------
1  |  0     1     0    200   1000
2  |  0     0     1    100
3  |  1     0     1    500
4  | 500   800   400
```

If you want to insert the capacity into formula as a literal, clear E1 and edit formula to

```
=1000-SUMPRODUCT(A1:A3,$D1:$D3)
```

PS. Maybe you must to use a semicolon `;` instead of comma `,` in a formula - check it.

Comment: Perfect!  Just what I was looking for.